# How to get node and edge count with Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, gprof

I got my graph with using gprof,gprof2dot.py and Graphviz.However i want to access the information of how many nodes,edges there.

I compiled the code with profiling enabled , so after running the executable gmon.out was created. Then gprof ./xmltest ./gmon.out > result.txt
result.txt contains generated flat profile and call graph information.

After that used this command gprof ./xmltest | ./gprof2dot.py | dot -Tpng -o result.png  to create the visualized graph. However, i need the number of nodes and edges but i cannot access that info.

Comment: Please provide information about what you already did and why it dit not work for you. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using gprof ./executable | ./gprof2dot.py > foo.dot , after that

gc foo.dot command returns the number of nodes and edges.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information from .dot file using graphviz gc tool.
For example, assume that you have a graph file sample.dot

you can type the following:

```
gc -n -e sample.dot
```

this will return how many nodes and edges the graph in sample.dot has.
a full reference on how can you write a gc command can found [her](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gc.1.pdf)